# How we can delete some words with PHP functions?

Tags: php

I want to change a text in my page, but when I used `preg_replace` , the text which should change, wasn't deleted.

I want to delete this text from my page, and replace that PHP code.

My code is this:

```
preg_replace("<-username->", $some_func->username(), "");
```

and the page shows that:

> admin 123 <-username-> // that should be deleted from my page

Then at the end I want to say, if you have some article for reguler extension I'm grateful to give me them.

Comment: You don't need regex here, use [str_replace()](http://php.net/str_replace) instead: `$new_content = str_replace('<-username->', $some_func->username(), $your_original_content);`

Comment: Does it have to follow the `<-username->` format in your page? I mean it's php we're talking about: you could have `{$username}` instead, include the page in your script, and the replacement would be done for you automatically, provided that the `$username` variable is populated.

Comment: Thank you , but what should I write in $your_original_content ?

Comment: It should be `$new_content = str_replace('<-username->', "", $some_func->username());`

Answer (score 2):

`"<-username->"` is not a valid regular expression. `"/<-username->/"` is.

Look at the [docs for pcre at php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/pcre.pattern.php), they are very good.

Answer (score 2):

Use `"/<-username->/"` instead of  `"<-username->`" in `preg_replace("<-username->", $some_func->username(), "");`

i.e `preg_replace("/<-username->/", $some_func->username(), "");`

Answer (score 0):

Your example doesn't require full regular expression engine to find the matching string. Just use [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) like:

```
$new_content = str_replace('<-username->', "", $some_func->username());
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$str = "Hello World!";

$clean_str = chop($str,"World!");
```